# How to set the value of LimitRequestLine on Plesk Onyx

Tags: apache, plesk-onyx

I'm using Plesk Onyx now. I want to set the value of "LimitRequestLine" of Apache config. But I was not able to find the setting file and screen. Where is there?

Comment: I have the same problem and would appreciate an answer how to increase the "LimitRequestLine" and "LimitRequestFieldSize" in Plesk Onyx. Adding the values to the settings for Apache & nginx doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apache documentation:](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#limitrequestline)

> Warning When name-based virtual hosting is used, the value for this
>   directive is taken from the default (first-listed) virtual host best
>   matching the current IP address and port combination

this directives are taken from IP_ADDRESS:PORT

So in order to set LimitRequestLine and LimitRequestFieldSize it's needed:

1. Login to Plesk using admin account. If you do not have admin account contact your hosting provider.
2. Set example.com as the default site at **Tools & Settings > IP Addresses** and click on your IP
3. Go to **Domains > example.com > Additional Apache & nginx Directives** and add the following directives to **Additional directives for HTTP and HTTPS**:

`LimitRequestLine 16380
LimitRequestFieldSize 16380`

Note: this directives will be used by all domains assigned to this IP.
If you have example2.com already set as Default site for IP then it's needed to add this directives to **Domains > example2.com > Additional Apache & nginx Directives**